# SSH connection to Amazon EC2 with private key fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm trying to connect to the problematic Amazon EC2 instance with this command:

```
ssh -vvv -i MY_KEY.pem root@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

and getting this result:

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0g-fips  2 Nov 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 8: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com [XX.XX.XXX.XX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file MY_KEY.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file MY_KEY.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:rRMQg/hs
debug1: Host 'ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/dina/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: MY_KEY.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering RSA public key: dina@localhost.localdomain
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: MY_KEY.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

The key MY_KEY.pem should be correct, I've checked the fingerprint under NETWORK & SECURITY -> Key Pairs on AWS console, and it's the same as for the key I'm using.

Permissions for the .pem file is 400, owner is current owner. SSH inbound traffic to the instance is allowed from all addresses.

Also tried this with different users (root, ubuntu, admin, ec2-user,  centos, fedora) as I have no contact with the person who launched the instance and have no idea what system is there.

Any idea about what is going on and what could be done about it? Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: Make a snapshot of this volume and attach it to another instance (where you can log in) and inspect /home folder

Comment: The public key for `MY_KEY.pem` needs to be in the target user's (in this case `root`'s) `.ssh/authorized_keys` for you to be able to log in with the pem file.  Also check how `PermitRootLogin` is set in the server sshd config and make sure it allows remote root login.

Answer (score 1):

What AMI are you using?

If you are using an Ubuntu AMI, you should connect as ubuntu.

`$ ssh -vvv -i ~/.ssh/MY_KEY.pem ubuntu@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

On Amazon Linux, the default user is ec2-user.

`$ ssh -vvv -i MY_KEY.pem ec2-user@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Once you are in both of these users will have sudo privileges.

Comment: Figured out the user is root. When I'm trying to connect with ubuntu/ec2-user, the instance screenshot shows log from sshd: "Invalid user", but the root gives "Tally overflowed for user root"